# Clicking on leaflet js stops working on mobile

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, leaflet

I've got a Cordova (Ionic) mobile app with Leaflet JS (ver 0.7.7) and I'm displaying a map with 2 markers which also have Popups.

Now on my iOS, when I touch a marker it opens the popup as expected, but after jumping backwards and forwards between the two markers about 6 - 10 times, Leaflet stops receiving the "click" event (all other events are received).

On the browser this works perfectly all the time with the same code.  I've spend hours on this already and traced it down to the fact that the HTML element no longer seems to receive the 'click' event, even it I do a $('element').click().

Btw: I've done the data-tap-disabled="true" on the mapping HTML parent so I know it's not that.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just found out this issue is being caused by the use of this plugin https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView   Anyone have an idea?

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, I've found the solution here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4506